# Transforming raw scores to scaled scores using a proprietary scale

Tags: spss, data-transformation, standardization, excel, scales

I'm working with questionaire answers from the Child Behavior Checklist (CBCL) for my master's thesis. The 113 items on the questionaire are organized into several subscales for different areas of behavior (e.g. thought problems.) I have raw scores for each subscale (for example, if a participant answered 7 of the 10 questions associated with 'thought problems' in the positive, their raw score would be 10.) However, the company responsible for the CBCL has developed a rubric for standardizing these scores for children of particular age ranges and genders, called the T score. As far as I can tell, it's not strictly related to Z or T transformations.

I'm using SPSS to analyze the data but I'm more comfortable with Excel for fancy formulas. I would like to find a way to convert my raw scores to T scores via my computer using their rubric. I have an inkling that this might be possible if I enter the T-score conversion rubric into another spreadsheet and write a formula that references it, but I'm not sure how to do that. E.g: a raw score of 2 converts to a T score of 47. Can anybody help me? Please let me know if you need further clarification of the problem.

Comment: Without knowing the details of the implementation we cannot asnwer this.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for replying! What do you mean by implementation? The version of SPSS I'm using is 24.

Comment: What is this "T score" you speak of? How is it calculated? What is the formula? What is a rubric?